# Logical error in insertion of node in a BST

Tags: c++, tree

I have written a node insertion code for a BST. But it dosen't seem to work correctly. Its giving a "Segmentation error". Here is my logic for insertion.

```
    void insert(Node* root, int data){
     if(root==NULL){
      root= new Node;
      root->data = data;
      }
    else if(data < root->data){
      insert(root->left,data);
      }
    else if(data> root->data){
      insert(root->right,data);
      }
    }
```

How do i fix it? Thanks

Edit: so i tried out some things and this one does the trick

```
    Node* insert(Node* &root, int data){
    if(root==nullptr){
    root = create(data);
    return root;
    }
    else if(data < root->data){
    insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else if(data> root->data){
    insert(root->right,data);
    } 
    }
```

Whats the difference between Node* root and Node* &root ?

Comment: First, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Second, are you sure that `left` and `right` fields are initialized correctly? Third, think in using `unique_ptr` instead of naked pointer

Comment: There's not enough here to give a definite answer.  Where does it crash?  In `insert`, or after the `insert` call?  You're assigning to the local `root` variable so no changes ever propagate back to the caller.

Comment: Regarding your edit: the difference is the same as that between `int x` and `int& x`. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Difference between `Node* a` and `Node*& b` is that you refresh node parent's `l` or `r` pointers (in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55874625/7340043) it's 'hanging up'). Just like if you have `void f(int a) { a = 5; }` and `void g(int& a) { a = 5; }` and after calling `f(x)` `x` still stores it's prevous value, but after `g(x)` `x` stores `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if node doesn't exists (it's `NULL`), you're just setting your `root` pointer to `new Node`, but you're missing to 'hang it up' to it's parent. And as already mentioned, you can use `unique_ptr`-s since `C++11` to avoid memory leaks (that's when you forget to delete object). It looks like:

```
struct Node {
    int data = -1;  // not initialized
    std::unique_ptr<Node> l;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> r;
}

void insert(Node *root, int data) {
    if (root->data == -1) {
        root->data = data;
        return;
    }
    if (data < root->data) {
        if (!root->l) {
            // hanging new left node up
            root->l = std::make_unique<Node>();  // std::make_unique comes since C++14
        }
        insert(root->l.get(),  // getting raw ptr
               data);
    }
    else {
        if (!root->r) {
             // hanging new right node up
             root->r = std::make_unique<Node>();
        }
        insert(root->r.get(), data);
    }
}
```

Also you might be interested in data structure called [treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap), because your implementation may work very long if you insert, for example, increasing sequence:

```
Node root;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100'000; i++) {
    insert(&root, i);
}
```

So your binary tree in this case looks like:

```
1
 \                  
  2                 <=
   \                <= very long path
    3               <=
     \
     ...
       \
     100'000
```

Treap helps to avoid long paths in your BST.